# Magento 2 : TypeError: Argument 1 passed

Tags: magento2

I am getting below error on rest api call on this method

```
public function handleDecline($order)
    {
        $result = $this->forterConfig->getDeclinePost();
        if ($result == '1') {
            $this->customerSession->setForterMessage($this->forterConfig->getPostThanksMsg());
            if ($order->canHold()) {
                $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
                $this->decline->holdOrder($order);
                $this->setMessageToQueue($order, 'decline');
            }
        } elseif ($result == '2') {
            $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
            $this->decline->markOrderPaymentReview($order);
        }

        throw new PaymentException($this->forterConfig->getPostThanksMsg());
    }
```

TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException::__construct() must be an instance of
Magento\Framework\Phrase, string given, called in

Any thoughts how this can be solved ?

```
I think this is related to type of "$this->forterConfig->getPostThanksMsg()"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that:

```
throw new PaymentException(__($this->forterConfig->getPostThanksMsg()));
```

Comment: Hello, can you share your thoughts on this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/335649/magento-2-no-such-entity-with-fieldname