# Magento 2 : No such entity with %fieldName

Tags: magento2, orders, quote, magento2.4

I am getting this error any thoughts, why this error appearing ?

```
"message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "cartId",
        "fieldValue": 0
    },
    "trace": "#0
```

/Magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(232):

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to test it just by the information that you provide, although I have some clue what is wrong: `fieldValue` is 0, no entity will return a cart for this value.

If you are performing the request for guest user you can check the table `quote_id_mask` but the `fieldValue` must be a hash. For logged users `fieldValue` needs be an int greater than 0 and that is the entity_id for `quote` table

Can you share which Magento version are you performing?

I had a similar problem using Magento 2.1, therefore include that information might be relevant.

Good luck.

Comment: Thankyou for your thoughts, i am using Magento/2.4 (Enterprise)